# Vue 3 Composition API - How to specify a prop in setup()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-mixin

I wrote a "loading state" mixin for Vue 2:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
  },
  data () {
    return {
      innerLoading: false,
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.innerLoading = !!this.loading
  },
  methods: {
    startLoading () {
      this.$emit('update:loading', this.innerLoading = true)
    },
    stopLoading () {
      this.$emit('update:loading', this.innerLoading = false)
    },
  },
  computed: {
    isLoading () {
      return !!this.innerLoading
    },
    isNotLoading () {
      return !this.innerLoading
    },
  },
  watch: {
    loading (loading) {
      this.innerLoading = !!loading
    },
  }
}
```

I use this mixin for other components to hold the `loading` state. For example for forms, buttons, tables etc.

Now, Im trying to rewrite this mixin to composition API style for Vue 3. Ideally, I would like to use my `loading` composable like this:

```js
// components/Table.vue

import 'useLoading' from 'src/composables/loading'

export default defineComponent({
  setup () {
    const { startLoading, stopLoading, innerLoading } = useLoading()

    // ...
    
    return { startLoading, stopLoading, innerLoading, ... }
  }
})
```

My question:

```js
// How can I define the loading prop inside the setup() function?
props: {
  loading: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
},
```

Of course I can define my component like this:

```js
import 'useLoading' from 'src/composables/loading'

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    loading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
  },
  setup () {
    const { startLoading, stopLoading, innerLoading } = useLoading();
  }
})
```

But imagine, I have 20 components using this mixin/composable. So I want to define that `loading` prop only **ONCE** (like I did in mixin).

Is there a way how to do it with composition API?

Comment: @mspiderv `props` can't be declared inside `setup()`. Since `setup()` itself receives the `props` values as its second argument, `props` would have to be declared before `setup()` is even invoked. Currently, the only way to declare `props` is using the Options API.

Comment: How did you finally implement this? How did you get access to `loading` prop in the watcher within the composable?

Comment: @Donkarnash I implement it by creating two functions: `useLoading` and `withLoading`. The `useLoading` contains the whole logic and `withLoading` returns props exactly like @Daniel said (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66604160/2987610). I don't use watcher in my new implementation, but't it seems to me like you are asking something else.

Comment: Thanks for response. in `useLoading` where you have all the logic how do you access the `props` of component which is using the `useLoading` composable? I can understand that in the consuming component you include `...withLoading()` to declare the prop `loading` but then how do you get access to the prop in `useLoading`?

Comment: @Donkarnash Like this: `export function useLoading (props, ctx) { props.loading; }` But of course, you need to pass `props` and `ctx` to `useLoading` like this: `setup (props, ctx) { const { ... } = useLoading(props, ctx); return [ ... ] }` Another syntax is this: `setup(props, ctx) { return [ ...useLoading(props, ctx) ] }` or this: `setup: useLoading`

Comment: @Donkarnash The whole trick is that you receive the `props` variable as the first argument in the `setup` function. Then you just need to pass this `props` variable to your `useLoading` function. You can also pass the second `ctx` argument if you want.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for the elaborate response. I thought that there's some "magic" way :). I'm using `<script setup>` so I declare props with `defineProps({})`. Will need to pass the props as an arg to the `useSomething(props)` which I thought can be circumvented in some way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you may be able to do something like this

```js
import {withProps, useLoading} from "src/composables/loading";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    ...withProps()
  },
  setup () {
    const { startLoading, stopLoading, innerLoading } = useLoading();
  }
})
```

where `withProps` is a function that would have your definitions

```js
export const withProps = () => ({
  loading: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
})
```

of course it doesn't need to be a function, but in some cases it may be helpful and preemptively making it a function can make api consistent.

Answer (score 4):

Define an Object called `loadingProps` in separate file called `makeLoadingProps`:

```js
export const loadingProps = {
    loading: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    }
}
```

then import it inside your component defined using the **script setup** syntax:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

import {defineProps} from 'vue'
import { loadingProps } from 'src/composables/makeLoadingProps';

const props = defineProps({
               ...loadingProps,
                //other props
             })

const { startLoading, stopLoading, innerLoading } = useLoading(props)

</script>
```

Comment: MIXINS ARE NO LONGER RECOMENDED! In Vue 2, mixins were the primary mechanism for creating reusable chunks of component logic. While mixins continue to be supported in Vue 3, Composition API is now the preferred approach for code reuse between components. (From the Vue manual)

Comment: Thank you for this reminder, I'll try to update my answer later

Comment: What would be the return type of `loadingProps` in TypeScript?